# Missing fields / columns on NewForm.aspx

Tags: 2010, list

I have a list in SharePoint 2010 in which the fields are not shown when clicking "New Item" and opening the NewForm.aspx. The list is not using a custom content type. I can edit existing list items in the list without any issue.

What might be causing this?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which fields are missing (more importantly their type), and is this a custom list? and If not, did you add any of your own fields to the oob List (and what type is it)?

Comment: All of the fields are missing on NewForm.aspx, but all are visible on EditForm.aspx. This is a custom list no custom developed columns.

Comment: I went in via PowerShell, and the fields are not set to readonly, and I set explicitely to show in NewForm and the fields still don't show.

Answer (score 1):

Close your sharepoint designer and open your site again in sharepoint designer, check NewForm.aspx now. If you are still not able to see missing fields, create a new form you will see the fields in new form.

Comment: How do you propose making a new NewForm.aspx without deleting the list?